# Configure Artifactory Cloud as private Docker Registry

Tags: artifactory, docker-registry

I'm using following [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Docker+Repositories) to configure private Docker Registry in Artifactory Cloud.
I've configured Docker Registry from UI with V2 API and force authentication.

Let's skip reverse proxy configuration for now. I'm trying to call artifactory directly to verify if it works:

```
curl --user test:test --connect-timeout 5 http://myaccountname-docker-dockerv2-local.artifactoryonline.com/artifactory/api/docker/dockerv2-local/v2/_ping
```

Notes:

- **test** - username and password
- **myaccountname** - my account name in Artifactory Cloud
- **dockerv2-local** - created docker registry repository (in Artifactory notation)

I've got response:

```
<html> 
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx</center>
</body>
</html>
```

I tried to use:

- myaccountname.artifactoryonline.com - the same result

and this

- myaccountname.artifactoryonline.com:**8080**
- myaccountname-docker-dockerv2-local.artifactoryonline.com:**8080**
- myaccountname.artifactoryonline.com:**8081**
- myaccountname-docker-dockerv2-local.artifactoryonline.com:**8081**

I got connection timeout.

---

I've spent a lot of time to figure out the root cause of this problem. I need you help, guys.

Can you tell me what I've done wrong? How to fix it? Or at least give me direction to look at.

Comment: Are you using Artifactory Online? Than you should make sure you have dockerv2-local repository and than you should access it with <account>-docker-dockerv2-local.artifactoryonline.com/<repo>:<version>
What is the output when you try to push:
<account>-docker-dockerv2-local.artifactoryonline.com/<repo>?

Comment: @Shikloshi I tried the formate <account>-<docker-repo-name>.artifactoryonline.com/ubuntu:latest and all I get back is "Error: image ubuntu not found"

Comment: @Shikloshi - By the way, the "Set Me Up" info for Docker is woefully inadequate.